Is it possible to bind [formControl] to an array of form control in Angular?
EDITED
I am working on a project which requires a user to click a button (to add multiple forms) that will show a form group (the form group resides in a form array) with 2 form controls that are both dropdown menus (mat-select in this case). 1 mat-select with single value selection and 1 mat-select with multiple values selection. The values of the 2nd mat-select depends on the selected value on the 1st drop down menu. So basically I have the code below:
loadForm() {
  return this._formBuilder.group({
    parentForm: this._formBuilder.array([])
  })
}

And then upon clicking the button, parentForm should add 2 dropdowns (mat-select), 1 single value selection and 1 for multiple values selection as mentioned above. For this, I have following code below:
addForm() { this.arrayOfForms().push(this.form()) }


arrayOfForms(): FormArray {
return this.form.get('field2') as FormArray }

form(): FormGroup {
  return this._formBuilder.group({
    field1: new FormControl(''),
    field2: this._formBuilder.array([])
  })
}

Upon refreshing the page, the values of both mat-select drop downs should be retained. However, the 2nd mat-select with multiple options enabled does not retain its previously selected values.
My question is how do I populate the 2nd mat-select with its previously selected values after the page is refreshed?

I think what you are looking for is a FormArray:
https://angular.dev/api/forms/FormArray
You can initialize it with the FormBuilder this.formBuilder.array([...]) or new FormArray([...])
Initialize like so:

... some component

form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array([]) // initialize or add new form controls
    });
  }

And use a small function to get it in the template:
get items() {
  return this.form.get('items') as FormArray;
}


Thanks for commenting. I've already figured it out.
